# Error al borrar registro en SqlLite

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y tengo muchísimas dudas.

Lo primero es que estoy haciendo un registro de personas, tengo la BD en sqlite, ya he logrado que ***guarde, busque y elimine*** la información, esto lo muestro en un `listview`, pero al momento de borrar varios datos se detiene la aplicación, por ejemplo:

Tengo 3 registros, elimino el primero y todo va bien, pero trato de seleccionar el segundo y ya no funciona y el tercero me lo toma como si fuera el segundo. Les agradecería mucho si pudieran ayudarme :)

```
 private  void consultar(){
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this,"Persona",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select ID, nombre, direccion, telefono from Persona";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listado);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String linea = c.getInt(0)+" "+c.getString(1)+" "+c.getString(2)+" "+c.getString(3);
            listado.add(linea);

        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
}
private void btnGuardar(String nombre, String direccion, String telefono){
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this,"Persona",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    try
    {
        ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
        c.put("nombre",nombre);
        c.put("direccion",direccion);
        c.put("telefono",telefono);
        db.insert("Persona",null,c);
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Registro insertado...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private int buscarRegistro(int pos) {
    pos++;
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this,"Persona",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();



    String sql = "SELECT id, nombre, telefono, direccion from Persona WHERE ID="+ pos;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    Nombre.setText(c.getString(1));
    Direccion.setText(c.getString(2));
    Telefono.setText(c.getString(3));
    return pos;
}
private void eliminar(int pos) {

    int posicion = pos;
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this, "Persona", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM Persona WHERE id ="+posicion;
        db.execSQL(sql);
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Registro Eliminado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: "+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: El problema probablemente sea el parámetro `pos` que le mandas al método. Estás seguro de que existe el registro con id igual a la posicion que le mandas? para ayudarte mejor deberiamos ver el código en el que llamas a `eliminar`

Comment: ¿has probado a volver a regenerar la lista después de cada borrado de registros?

Comment: Pon la clase que invoca a estos métodos, y si puedes el log de error

Comment: Lo mas probable es que estas eliminado el regitros en base a la posicion del elemento que seleccionas en el `ListView`. Deberias de enviar el id, no la posición.

Comment: German @GermanSilva siempre acostumbra agregar los mensajes de error desplegados dentro del LogCat, de esta forma los desarrolladores te pueden ayudar con mayor facilidad para encontrar el problema. Revisa [ask] como base para realizar una pregunta correctamente. No olvides realizar el [tour] saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando el parámetro `position` que se obtiene dentro del Adapter, recuerda que este valor en realidad es el indice del elemento dentro del adapter, recuerda que el primer indice siempre es el 0, por ejemplo:

```
position = 0 ; es el primer elemento.
position = 1 ; es el segundo elemento.
position = 2 ; es el tercer elemento.
position = 3 ; es el cuarto elemento.
etc....
```

Por lo tanto si envias el valor de position puede que no coincida con el id que tienes registrado en tu tabla, ya que seguramente los id inician desde 1 y no desde 0.

Puedes enviar el valor de position y dentro modificarlo para que sea el valor del id del registro aunmentando en 1 el valor.

```
private void eliminar(int pos) {

    int posicion = pos + 1; //* Agrega +1 para que coincida con el id del elemento.

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this, "Persona", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM Persona WHERE id ="+posicion;
        db.execSQL(sql);
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Registro Eliminado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: "+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

---

De hecho si revisas tu método `buscarRegistro()`, en realidad se esta realizando lo que comento anteriormente.

```
private int buscarRegistro(int pos) {

    pos++;  //*  Agrega +1 para que coincida con el id del elemento.

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this,"Persona",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();



    String sql = "SELECT id, nombre, telefono, direccion from Persona WHERE ID="+ pos;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    Nombre.setText(c.getString(1));
    Direccion.setText(c.getString(2));
    Telefono.setText(c.getString(3));
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Aun no he podido solucionarlo :(, gracias por responder y disculpa pero no tengo casi nada de conocimiento trato de aprender. String sql = "SELECT id, nombre, telefono, direccion from Persona WHERE ID="+ pos;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    c.moveToFirst(); //Aqui me falta agregar la posicion 0, pero no se como agarrar el id, ya que no esta dentro de un edittext
    Nombre.setText(c.getString(1));
    Direccion.setText(c.getString(2));
    Telefono.setText(c.getString(3));

Comment: Como que no lo has solucionado? Que problema se tiene ahora, ya revisaste el LogCat ?

Comment: @GermanSilva dentro del método buscarRegistro() cambia de  pos++;  a int posicion = pos + 1;  y   String sql = "SELECT id, nombre, telefono, direccion from Persona WHERE ID="+ posicion;

Comment: El error esta en ese metodo de buscar, y puse eso de la posicion y sigue deteniendose:`
        c.moveToFirst();
//justo aqui me marca el LogCat, faltara poner el id? pero como lo agarro ya que me lo da automaticamente u.u
        Nombre.setText(c.getString(1));
        Direccion.setText(c.getString(2));
        Telefono.setText(c.getString(3));

        return pos;
    }`